# build static array of objects at build time not runtime?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I'm wanting to avoid trying to manage multiple static arrays in my vue code.
Currently I have a long json for i18Next and am using this to generate pre-requisite arrays of objects for vue-treeselect at runtime.. but I can see it grinding and the performance is noticeably laggy

Since I don't actually need to build these arrays at runtime, is there a build/dev time way of doing it?

Converting the i18next json to the array is currently done by this

```
export function walk(item) {
    const mainArray = [];
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
        const objectLiteral = {};
        objectLiteral.id = key;
        objectLiteral.label = 'later - gen key';
        if (typeof item[key] === "object") {
            
            const arrayTemp = [];
            //we need to create an array of objects here and assign them to 'children' in the parent
            Object.keys(item[key]).forEach((key2) => {
                if (key2.slice(-3) === 'gen') {
                    objectLiteral.label = item[key][key2];
                } else { 
                const objectTemp = {};
                objectTemp.id = key2;
                objectTemp.label = item[key][key2];
                arrayTemp.push(objectTemp);
                }
            });
            objectLiteral.children = arrayTemp;
        }
        mainArray.push(objectLiteral)
    });
    return mainArray;
}
```

I'm using vite as a dev/build environment

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which build tool you use for the project you can always generate these things in the build pipeline of the bundler.

In Webpack for example you could simply run a script and inject the result as a variable since it is just JavaScript.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Other build tools also have the ability to run scripts during the build step.

EDIT: as baradhili mentioned himself you can set up a script in the package.json via "node script.js" for example to run a script during build time with other build tools. That way you can pre-build the data arrays.

Comment: I'm running vite.. but I suspect I can use node to run js code to do the work, it just won't be hot-running

Comment: I am not too familar with vite. Doesn't alow vite to inject variables to the app?

Comment: Sure, it just doesn't execute external scripts as it doesn't bundle anything in dev mode.. But I can execute the externals via package.json using "node script.js" and that works.. Do you think you could expand your answer to cover that? that way I'll accept your answer instead of adding my own..

Comment: Sure, thats also an idea to run it via the npm package,json and then just run them before the build :)